# Can Azure AD OAuth client credentials flow permissions be limited to specific mailboxes?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I have a background service that needs to be able to monitor specific mailboxes for new emails in a customer's Azure AD. Because it's a background service, I'd like to use the [OAuth client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

To test this out, I registered an application in my own Azure AD (allowing accounts in any organizational directory), and am looking at setting the permissions. My understanding is that, for the client credentials flow, I can only set application-level permissions, not delegated. I see a Mail.Read permission for all mailboxes, but not a way to choose specific ones.

Am I missing the right way to set this up, or is switching to the [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) with delegated permissions my only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: You need to pass only application permissions while using Client Credential flow. As there is no user context involved in this flow, they are tenant-wide permissions.

- **Hence**, if you use Client Credential Flow the Azure AD Application will have same level access to all the mailboxes.

You can make use of **Authorization code flow** which needs delegated permissions which allows to request access.

I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API permissions** like below:

[image]

Authorized users using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Read
&state=12345
```

[image]

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Read
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

Using the above access token, you can read the mails like below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
```

[image]

**Otherwise**, you can also try limiting the Application to specific mailboxes by creating the **Application policy** by referring this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access#configure-applicationaccesspolicy):

```bash
New-ApplicationAccessPolicy -AppId AppClientID -PolicyScopeGroupId xxx@xxx.com -AccessRight RestrictAccess -Description "Restrict this app to members"
```

**Reference:**

[Get message - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of how the authorization code flow works, but your last point about the application policy sounds like exactly what I've been looking for.