# How to use Azure App Roles using PHP and Postman

Tags: php, azure, postman, roles, php-curl

Several questions about Azure App Roles and PHP.

As I understand it, I can get the app roles either by REST API or Microsoft Graph. I was hoping to use the API route and found some posts on Stack overflow that help, but I'm not there yet.

I am hoping to setup the request in Postman, get it working, then export the PHP code (cURL). The ultimate goal is to setup roles for my app service for different levels of access determined by role.

The GET request URL I am using is (with subscription ID filled in):
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTIONID/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup1/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?api-version=2022-04-01&$filter=atScope()

I get Authentication Failed because I don't really understand how to authenticate into Azure to process this request - I've seen someone using a bearer token, but I'm not sure how to do that, or where the bearer token comes from?

I've done a fair bit of reading and will continue to but wanted to post this in case someone has some sample PHP code, information on bearer tokens, or can offer any help regarding postman.

Thanks!

I've tried using Postman but can't authenticate.

Comment: For any of these complicated providers, I personally find that it isn't worth trying to figure out the entire flow and instead rely on a library such as https://github.com/TheNetworg/oauth2-azure

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: If you want to call the API without user interaction then make use of client credential flow. If you want user interaction, make use of Authorization code flow to generate the access token.

Create an Azure AD application and grant API permissions:

[image]

*Based on your requirement you can select any token grant flows to authenticate. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).*

For ***sample***, I used **Client Credential flow** by using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://management.azure.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

**Note** that: You must assign **`Reader`** role to the application to call the API.

[image]

Using the access token, **I am able to call the API successfully** like below:

```json
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SUBID/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup1/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?api-version=2022-04-01
```

[image]

**References:**

[GitHub - CoasterKaty/PHPAzureADoAuth: PHP Azure AD login with demo site (using oAuth)](https://github.com/CoasterKaty/PHPAzureADoAuth) by CoasterKaty

[Can Azure AD OAuth client credentials flow permissions be limited to specific mailboxes? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76213017/can-azure-ad-oauth-client-credentials-flow-permissions-be-limited-to-specific-ma) by me